# What is wrong with this item stats?

Tags: diablo-iii

[image]

The left spear has

- 45% damage
- higher intelligence bonus
- higher damage per second. Due to the same attack speed, that means the same damage by the way.

So why is my DPS lower with the left spear?  That doesn't seem to make sense.

One possible explanation is that the 45% is already counted in computing DPS.

Update: Turns out the left spear has lower DPS. Never mind. I missed that somehow. That, along with the idea that 45% damage is already incorporated would explain why the left hit less hard.

Comment: I do not believe anyone has figured out what the item value calculations are; it's such a miniscule amount compared to the auction house, that it makes no real difference.

Comment: NB: the damage increase is already accounted for in the displayed damage of the weapon. More displayed dps, more expensive from the looks of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close your question since it's not clear what you're asking. If you  clarify your question then it's possible for your question to be re-opened if it's a valid question for the site.

Comment: Wow. I am asking why the tip says that my damage will be reduced with the left weapon. Why is this a bad question?

Comment: I'd recommend looking [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-dps-calcu).  It may help you.

Comment: Okay. I missed that. I understand why. Still, why is this a bad question?

Comment: It's already been asked; see [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75955/how-is-the-weapon-damage-on-this-weapon-calculated), specifically, for weapon percentage damage.  That one took a bit of doing to find, though, so it's understandable if you couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that both the +45% damage stat and the +elemental damage stat is incorporated into the DPS figures quoted on the item.

In this instance you're comparing the following two items;

**Lancer's Avenger**

> ```
> DPS: 634.6
> +189 Intelligence
> +178 Vitality
> ```

vs

**Striking Pike**

> ```
> DPS: 661.8
> +181 Intelligence
> +117 Vitality
> Life on hit +918
> ```

I would not expect the price difference to be caused by the 8 additional intelligence on the item and the other two stats in this instance are calculated into the DPS value on the item, which turns out to be slightly lower than that of the Striking Pike, leaving the difference between the two as vitality.

Comment: I made a mistake. Turns out the left weapon has lower damage. Also the 45% is already taken into account. Still I think it's a good question with a good answer. Not sure why it's closed. I am not asking about item valuation.

Comment: The answer is about item valuation. If the question is not, then no... This is not a good question with a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

At a guess, I'd say it's because the one on the left has four affixes.  Don't be fooled by the number of stats, and pat attention to the fact that the Vitality on the spear on the right is noticeably lower. This is because it *probably* has an Int/Vit affix rather than separate Int and Vit affixes.  There's no good reason to expect the games valuation formula to place a premium on damage, or, for that matter, on any other stat in the way that the player base does.

Beyond that, as Fbueckert notes, item valuation is not particularly well understood, and, more importantly, completely and totally irrelevant for all but the absolute worst and lowest level items, so the real answer here is: **Who Cares?**

Answer (score 0):

Your image is a little too small to read the text, but it looks like the weapon on the right has +900 life on hit.  This makes it a great weapon for people who are building tanky like Barbarians or Monks.  900+ life on hit on a 1-hander is on the higher end of the scale.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8zOmS.jpg here's the big one.

Comment: Right click on the picture and click Show Image if you are using FF.