# How do I determine the true DPS increase?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been looking to upgrade my gear slowly, starting with my weapon. I've been looking at AH but I'm a bit uncertain as to how I should read out the differeces in DPS. The following SS show a Manticore that has higher stats than my current.
[image]

I can't really imagine that my current Manticore is the better one, but I guess that both crit chance and crit damage is taken into account.

So how can I determine if a certain piece of equipment really IS an improvement in DPS? This is my [profile](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/profile/Skyclad-2411/hero/7903139).

Comment: A couple related, perhaps duplicates: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-dps-calcu, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75955/how-is-the-weapon-damage-on-this-weapon-calculated

Comment: import your character with d3up.com and then simulate the gear.  And I'm pretty sure that the 1123 dps manticore will be far more dps once you put the gem in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So The first one is far better. However I recommend to **NEVER** put vitality on a weapon. Your weapon is your main source of DPS (as every stats is based on the DPS of your weapon). This means that you need only DPS stats on your weapon (Socket for emerald, Crit chance, Crit damage, Dext). Furthermore, if you ever need to replace your Manticore, you'll loose 100 vitality and will have to find it elsewhere.

Whenever you want to see your real eDPS (effective DPS) change go here :
 [Character calculator](http://d3up.com/build/create). On the right part : *Select your sever > Put your battletag > select the character you want to test > click on "Create Build" > Simulate Gear > Select your manticore and edit the stats*. While doing this on the right you will see the evolution of your eDPS depending on the weapon stats.

I've just tested and you gain ~2500 dps and ~17500 eHP

Comment: +1 for the point about vit.  I try not to put vit/EHP on my weapons and jewelry.  These are already typically the most expensive pieces of gear on the character and having to pad in additional vit/res there drives the prices through the roof.

Answer (score 0):

To see the true DPS increase you will have to buy it and equip it. But, to compare these 2 items you should unsocket one of the gems from your *Manticore*. And then you can treat both of them as 1-socket *Manticores*.

45% of *Critical Hit Damage* extra on your *Manticore* make that -4183.5 damage difference.

Comment: I believe the AH (when comparing like this) takes into account BOTH gems. Thus the -4183.5 damage difference is the difference of BOTH 45% Critical Damage gems (90% crit damage) and the difference in stats. To get a more accurate comparison, un-socket both gems and compare again.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv if you unsocket both gems, you won't get accurate results. You could put 1x 110% in one and 2x 110% in the other one. So to compare them more fairly, make sure that they have equal number of free sockets(or that they are socketed with the same gems)

Comment: We're both right; the comparison does use both gems to compare the damage (90% Crit Damage difference) BUT if you really want to compare them you should only un-socket one gem (for the reasons you mentioned)