# How do "stats changes if equipped" work in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am a little confused by this preview of the damage that could be done in Diablo 3

Dire Span is reporting to give me +1076 to damage.

When equipped however it in fact reduces my overall dam by nearly 1.5k.

So how is this calculated? Is it only a problem because of the % that is added on these weapons to the damage when strength is taken into account?

Whilst this question may appear similar to this: [How is the weapon damage on this weapon calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75955/how-is-the-weapon-damage-on-this-weapon-calculated)

However this question does not give information on strength factor.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think passives are taken into account on the mouse over.  Do you have weapon master for your passive?  That 10% crit hit chance can make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing the damage of 1 handed and 2 handed weapons, Diablo 3 doesn't take into account the stats of the item in your off hand. The comparison stats you're seeing are only comparing the new 2 handed weapon with the 1 handed weapon you have equipped. Since equipping the 2 handed weapon also unequips your shield, this causes your damage to decrease.

Comment: Yes, I thought this as well. That is why I took off my shield. As you case in the images :D